# Defining username and passwords using 'Basic Authentication' security

Tags: raml

Where do i define valid set of username and passwords for authentication using RAML.

Here is the RAML code i use.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't: RAML is an API definition language, what you're talking about is the security configuration of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
securitySchemes:
 - basic:
      type: Basic Authentication
```

https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/blob/master/dist/examples/simple.raml

Answer (score 1):

You ideally should not.

Try using other security schemes for authorizations and authentications.

[image]